# How do I locate the task submission triggering an exception in a dask computation?

Tags: python, debugging, dask, pdb

I'm trying to debug code that is using dask for calculations.  The exception traceback ends with:

```
  File "/media/nas/x21324/miniconda3/envs/py37d/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 118, in _execute_task
    args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
  File "/media/nas/x21324/miniconda3/envs/py37d/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 118, in <listcomp>
    args2 = [_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args]
  File "/media/nas/x21324/miniconda3/envs/py37d/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)
  File "/media/nas/x21324/miniconda3/envs/py37d/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/optimization.py", line 942, in __call__
    dict(zip(self.inkeys, args)))
  File "/media/nas/x21324/miniconda3/envs/py37d/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 149, in get
    result = _execute_task(task, cache)
  File "/media/nas/x21324/miniconda3/envs/py37d/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/core.py", line 119, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal
```

Which, many levels up, leads up to a `.compute(...)` call that is either called explicitly or a consequence of some other operation triggering a compute (in this case `numpy.ma.masked_invalid`).  The actual code triggering the bug is elsewhere, in the operation when the dask task is being scheduled.

Following the [dask debugging guidelines](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/docs/source/debugging.rst), I have run `dask.config.set(scheduler='single-threaded')`, but this appears to make no difference, as far as I can tell.

Is there a way I can configure dask to execute all tasks immediately upon submission, or some other way in which I get a traceback such that I can point the debugging to the line where the instruction was submitted?

---

(This is a warning, not an error, but I have turned it into an exception because I want to study the circumstances causing it)

Answer (score 0):

> I have run dask.config.set(scheduler='single-threaded'), but this appears to make no difference, as far as I can tell.

When you see the exception in the single-threaded scheduler, you are able to run `pdb.pm()` (or simply `pdb` in a ipython/jupyter session) as you would for any other exception, and thus find out the conditions at the time of the error.

Comment: Except that the time of the error is when `.compute()` is being executed.  That's too late, because at that point I don't know which task has triggered the error, and it can be laborious to find out.  I would need some scheduler that executes each task immediately upon submission, so that the execution, and thus the exception, does not get postponed until `.compute()`.

Comment: No, Dask doesn't do that, by design, lazy execution is essential for how it works.

Comment: I'm aware that's by design; but for debugging purposes, it would be very useful to temporarily disable that, or mock lazy execution to be not lazy at all.

Comment: You can propose it as an issue, but I doubt it will be picked up, since it would be difficult to "auto-compute". You would probably be better off sprinkling `.compute()` into your code. Have you tried https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#distributed.recreate_exceptions.ReplayExceptionClient.get_futures_error ?

Comment: I have not tried `get_futures_error` (I have tried `recreate_error_locally` as a kw argument), I will investigate how to use this (I'm still new to dask, I'm using a library that uses dask, so from my perspective it's all still mostly a black box)

Comment: dask has over 1000 pages of documentation, so it may take me some time too figure out how to use the `dask.distributed.recreate_exceptions.ReplayExceptionClient.get_futures_error` method to find out what triggered the exception.